# Android incorrect database encoding on assets folder

Tags: android, database, sqlite, encryption, utf-8

I'm trying to implement a simple pre populated database into my assets folder of my Android application which I will then query at a later point. But the problem I'm facing is an encoding issue which I can convert the database inside of Android studio but then it implements a password using cipher encryption.

My current process of adding the database to my project

1. Firstly I went through the process of building a simple database and table inside of the sqlitebrowser application and made sure that the encoding within the preferences section was set to UTF-8.

http://sqlitebrowser.org - Link to the application which I'm currently using to build the database.

2. After I was happy with the database I then simply copy and past it into my assets folder.
3. I'm now presented with the image below (example)

[image]

4.My next step is that I convert it to UTF-8 as requested but I thought the sqlite browser would of already put it in this format.

5.The Code will now build the database correctly and I can see it within my data folder.

6. I then take a copy of the database off the virtual device, but when attempting to open it using sqlitebrowser I'm presented by a window asking for a password (Cipher Encryption). Now when I first built the database at no point did I add a password, so this makes think when Android asked to covert it did it also implement encryption?

Going back to the main question, how can I build a simple database in UTF-8 format which I can then implement into Android Studio assets folder?

Comment: IIRC, .db is like .exe, it is a binary file. IT has a lot of unrecognized symbols because it isn't designed to be browsed in a file explorer like you are trying. AFAIK and assuming I remember correctly, the only way to see the content of a database is by querying the content of it. You can't browse the file to see what is in teh database

Comment: "I'm now presented with the image below (example)" -- um, what is that screenshot from? That does not look like sqlitebrowser. It looks a bit like Android Studio, in which case your problem is trying to open any sort of SQLite database in Android Studio.

Comment: Hello Zoe what is the best application for building a simple sqlite database which will be in UTF-8 format that I can then import into my assets folder? Hello Commonware as stated in 2. I then past the database into my assets folder which means 3 must be an image from the assets folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At step 2 **STOP** ignore steps 3 on. 
Instead step 3 write an application (perhaps using [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), there are numerous tutorials on using SQLiteAssetHelper) to open and use the Database.

Android Studio is not designed to browse/interogate SQLite files, so basically it doesn't have a clue what the underlying data means. However from your screen shot you can see that some of the data does in fact indicate an SQLite file.

For example the following is a screen shot of opening an SQLite Database, (actually created and used in an Android App) in Notepad++ (see any similarities?) :-

[image]

e.g. It starts with **`SQLite format 3`**, the below mentions **`tablestudent`** and then goes on with **`CREATE TABLE students (_id......`**

So in all likelihood the data is fine it just needs to be opened/used by something that knows how to interpret the data in the file i.e. SQLite.

What can be seen from your screen shot, is that in all likelihood you have a column named **`_id`**.

Therefore your an answer to your question (ignoring opinions such as the best) :-

> Hello Zoe what is the best application for building a simple sqlite
>   database which will be in UTF-8 format that I can then import into my
>   assets folder?

is, it looks as though you have a suitable tool already (personally I use SQlite Manager for maniuplating and interrogating SQLite Databases, can't say whether SQLite Brwowser is better or worse or the same). All you need to do now is ascertain how to do the new step 3.

regarding your statement

> I then past the database into my assets folder which means 3 must be
>   an image from the assets folder.

That's not the case, all it is is that Android Studio has made an attempt to open the file and perhaps believes that it should be an image. I suspect you could drop in a PDF or  Word document (might have to change the extension to fool Android Studio) and it may well come up with a similar response. i.e (not that I've tried this) it may be that Android Studio has not been designed to read in MS Word or PDF documents, so knows nothing about them.

Ok, tried this now, here's part of a PDF file (extension renamed to xxx, as AS opened it as a PDF with pdf extension) :-

[image]